# Why does my wallpaper look slightly desaturated?

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background, image-processing

Here's a screenshot of the original image overlaid on top of the same image set as wallpaper. The original is far more saturated.

Is this a bug or is there a setting I can tweak to get my wallpaper to be as saturated as the original image?

[image]

Comment: I do not know. I am not an expert on Ubuntu, but I think it is probably a bug.

Comment: Does this only happen with this image, or others as well? If the former, then maybe you are confusing two slightly different images?

Comment: @AibaraIduas I'm not confusing two slightly different images; it's the same image file exactly. Oddly it doesn't seem to happen with other images that I've tested.

Comment: @Matthew Bradley - That's bizarre. Maybe it's the image viewer processing the image in an odd way? Does it look the same in another program (GIMP, gThumb, etc.)? Otherwise I have no clue!

Comment: @AibaraIduas Yup! Looks vibrant in Firefox. Here's the original link: http://ppcdn.500px.org/76717925/610db68cc234da8a231e285424e0b216cc2b4975/2048.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture in question has an embedded color profile which can only be displayed by certain programs; Nautilus, which draws the desktop background, cannot. To be able to use the image as a desktop background, it needs to be converted.

The easiest way is to use Image Viewer to save the file as a .png. Open the file, then go to `File -> Save As...` Then either manually change the file extension or click the pull down menu that says `All files` and select .png.

Now set the new image as your background and the colors will look right.

If you want to keep it as a .jpg, you'll need to use GIMP. If you don't have GIMP installed, download it via the Software Center or type `sudo apt-get install gimp` into a terminal.

When you open the image, you will be presented with this dialog:
[image]

Click `Convert`. Now go to `File -> Export As...`, then save it as a .jpg (make sure that the quality parameter is set to 100).

Here's a screenshot of the proper image set as my desktop, but displayed incorrectly in an image viewer:[image]